# After using the tun mode of Clash in Linux, the "docker pull" command encountered an exception

Tags: linux, proxy, tun

After using the tun mode of Clash in Linux, the "docker pull" command reported the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": EOF
```

But use the "curl [https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/"](https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/%22) command, get the following error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

The clash YAML configuration is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFCR0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdPG3.png)

How to solve this problem